# Getting "NoSuchMethodException" error for class "android.graphics.FontFamily" when updated "targetSdkVersion" and "compileSdkVersion" to 30

Tags: android

When I updated compileSdkVersion to 30 then it starts showing error in my LoginActivity at the line where I called setContentView(See logs below)

> 2020-06-22 13:43:21.205 14538-14538/com.gravty.everyday
> W/gravty.everyda: Accessing hidden method
> Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->()V (greylist-max-q, reflection,
> denied) 2020-06-22 13:43:21.206 14538-14538/com.gravty.everyday
> E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for
> class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily. []
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
> at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.obtainFontFamilyCtor(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:321)
> at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:84)
> at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.(TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.java:36)
> at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.(TypefaceCompat.java:47)
> at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.findFromCache(TypefaceCompat.java:76)
> at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:393)
> at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:361)
> at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:339)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:430)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:204)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:105)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
> at com.gravty.everyday.views.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:53)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7989)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)

Comment: Show your code, and put error message into `code` brackets, please.

Comment: Same here. I know solution is to update, but I cannot do this (right now). Did you experience any negative impact? I don't see anything misbehave right now.
(I know updating is the solution, but not possible atm)

Answer (score 38):

I was also facing same error of FontFamily's method not found. Reason was

> TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.class //it's library was missing

By adding stable version of core library
`implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'`
(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) in gradle build file. It got fixed for me.

**UPDATE:**
Those who are using Appcompat library instead core library can use stable version of Appcompat library i.e. `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1` (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#version_131_3) as mentioned by @Thiago

Comment: Any alternatives ?, for those who didn't migrate to androidx.

Comment: @Garci if you are facing same TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.class missing, then you can try adding 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0' in your gradle file as per docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4, otherwise you need to debug to find missing class file.

Answer (score 10):

By upgrading the appCompat library to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

Has fixed my issue (same as yours)

Comment: Just updated to 1.3.0 and has solved my issue

Comment: Any idea for people using the old `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` lib?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was forgotten my IDE in "Offline Mode" and the cache was cleared. So on app load custom fonts were missing and couldn't downloaded. By openning Offline Mode from **Gradle** -> **Toggle Offline Mode**, I was able to run my app successfully.