# Getting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init>

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, nosuchmethoderror, android-api-30

I am getting this error ever since upgrading the SDK version to 30:

```java
    E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init>
```

The issue seems to be resolved for androidx users by updating the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` lib, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510732/getting-nosuchmethodexception-error-for-class-android-graphics-fontfamily-wh). I am still using support packages however (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7` at v28.0.0) with which I still encounter the issue.

I'm new to Android development and was hoping someone could suggest a fix other than migrating to androidx.

Comment: See solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181236/java-android-app-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-android-graphics-fontfamily-i - upgrade your androix depdendency